# How can I have Entity Framework work with my detached object graph?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

In my application we are getting a new instance of our `DbContext` for each HTTP request. In the normal workflow, we create an entity and start populating portions of it's navigation properties:

```
// Request 1
var foo = new Foo();
SessionStore.Add("Foo", foo);

// Request 2
var bar = BarDataService.GetBar(barId);

var foo = SessionStore.Get<Foo>("Foo");
foo.Bars.Add(bar);

// Request 3
var baz = BazDataService.GetBaz(bazId);

var foo = SessionStore.Get<Foo>("Foo");
foo.Baz = baz;
```

Once the object graph is fully populated, we insert the entity into the database:

```
var foo = SessionStore.Get<Foo>("Foo");
FooDataService.Add(foo); // BOOM!
```

The Add ordinarily just adds the entity to the `DbSet` and then calls save changes:

```
Set.Add(entity);
Context.SaveChanges();
```

Clearly, this fails due to the fact that the `foo` object contains multiple proxy objects, each of which are attached to different `DbContexts`. The solution we decided upon was to detach objects that we were receiving:

```
// Request 2 (modified)
var bar = BarDataService.GetBar(barId);
BarDataService.Detach(bar);
foo.Bars.Add(bar);

// Similar code for Request 3

var foo = SessionStore.Get<Foo>("Foo");
FooDataService.Add(foo); // Works
```

This works, *except* for the fact that this now creates new instances of the `Bar` and `Baz` objects.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must attach the related `Bar` and `Baz` objects before you add `foo` to the context. This puts the entities into state `Unchanged` and EF will only create the relationships between `foo` and the related entities instead of creating new `Bar` and `Baz` objects in the database:

```
foreach (var bar in foo.Bars)
    context.Bars.Attach(bar);
context.Bazs.Attach(foo.Baz);
context.Foos.Add(foo);
context.SaveChanges();
```